# Search hidden unlocked cells in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a protected sheet, in which most cells are locked, and a few aren't. I want the Find command (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) to search only the unlocked cells. Preferably I want to hide these cells, so the "Find" command will just jump the user to the correct area of the sheet.

Now, what happens is strange: if the sheet is unprotected, the "Find" finds all the cells (contaning the value I search for), either locked or unlocked, either hidden or not. That makes sense. Now, I protect the sheet, allowing only unlocked cells to be selected (I really don't want to allow selecting locked cells). Now, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> doesn't seem to do anything. It neither jumps to the next (unlocked) cell, nor displayes the 'not found' message. That's strange. So, in the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> box, I click the 'options' button, then 'Format...', and then, in the 'Protection' tab, there are two options: locked and hidden. Both are with black squares (does it mean half-selection??). I check the 'hidden' box, and then the 'Find' command displayes the 'Not Found' message, regardless of the value of the 'locked' box. Alternatively, if I uncheck both the 'hidden' and 'locked' boxes, the 'Find' command works just fine on the unlocked cells, regardless of whether they're hidden or not.

It seems like a bug, doesn't it?
Well, the simple workaround is to perform a formatted search each time, as described above. But I can't do it. I need to generate this file and send it to my customers, and can't rely on them to perform this complex search each time. So I need to either solve this problem (find a way to make 'Find' work fine on protected sheets) or make sure the default search is a formatetd search. The file was generated by Python's `xlsxwriter` module.

Can it handle the default search of Excel??

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I have a solution. It seems that the cells that are 'locked unhidden' are causing the problem (the search can find them, but the 'find next' option doesn't work then). So, I simply make sure that all cells are either locked & hidden or unlocked & unhidden. Now the search works fine, skipping all the locked (& hidden) cells.

I really don't know what good is that 'hidden' option. It only seems to cause problems, and doesn't actually hide anything (if you want to hide cells, you can hide a column/row, and this option doesn't seem to be related to this 'hidden cell' option).